# How to arrange products according to price?

Tags: list, sorting, flutter

I have tried multiple ways to arrange products according to their price from low to high but the program keeps showing error

> class string/int has no method sort

I want to arrange the products list according to price and weight.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'ProductModel.dart';


class ProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueSetter<ProductModel> _valueSetter;
  final ValueSetter<ProductModel>_valueRemoval;
  static bool name=false;
  ProductScreen(this._valueSetter,this._valueRemoval);

  @override
  _ProductScreenState createState() => _ProductScreenState();
}

class _ProductScreenState extends State<ProductScreen> {


  //Seller s=new Seller(myController, myController1, myController2, imageFile);


 final List<ProductModel> products = [
    ProductModel("A cow1", 300,"24",Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570042225831-d98fa7577f1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80")),
    ProductModel("C cow2", 400,"43",Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570042225831-d98fa7577f1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80")),
    ProductModel("B cow3",600,"67",Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570042225831-d98fa7577f1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80")),
    ProductModel("E cow4", 1000,"123",Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570042225831-d98fa7577f1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80")),
    ProductModel("D cow5", 900,"150",Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570042225831-d98fa7577f1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80")),
    ProductModel("F cow6",1200,"189",Image.network("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1570042225831-d98fa7577f1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80")),
   //ProductModel(Seller.myController.text,int.parse(Seller.myController2.text),Seller.myController1.text,Image.file(Seller.imageFile),),
    //myController etc are static memebers in sellers because only static members can be use in initializers of productModel
    //Use classname.parameter because you can't acces static members through object of class like s.myController.text would be wrong

  ];
  List<ProductModel> productsArranged=[];
  

 filterByPrice(products) {
   setState(() {
     ProductScreen.name=true;
     /*()productsArranged= products
         .where((products) =>
         (products.name).toLowerCase().contains(products.toLowerCase()))
         .toList(); */


   });
 }

 SortPrice(products){
   products.sort((a,b)=>a.compareTo(b));
 }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child:ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListTile(
           title:Text(products[index].name),
              leading:products[index].i,
              subtitle:Column(
                children:<Widget>[
                  !ProductScreen.name?Text("\$${products[index].price}", 
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),):SortPrice(products[index].price),
                  //Text(,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                //Text("\$${products[index].price}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                  
                  Text(products[index].weight.toString()+" kg",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                     // SortPrice(products[index].weight),

                  

                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[


                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle, color: Colors.green,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          widget._valueRemoval(products[index]);
                          SnackBar s = SnackBar(content: Text(
                              products[index].name + " removed from your cart"),
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,);
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(s);
                        },),


                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.red,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          widget._valueSetter(products[index]);
                          SnackBar s = SnackBar(content: Text(
                              products[index].name + " added to your cart"),
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3),
                            backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,);
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(s);
                        },),


                    ],),

                ], ),

              onTap: (){

              },

          //  ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index){
          return Divider();
        },
        itemCount: products.length
    ),);
  }
}
```

The below code is my ProductModel

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ProductModel{

    String name;
    int price;
    String weight;
    Image i;
    ProductModel(this.name,this.price,this.weight,this.i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will sort the list in the Accending order.

```
         products.sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
          for(ProductModel p in products) {
            print(p.price);
          }
```

**Output:**

```
I/flutter (19456): 300
I/flutter (19456): 400
I/flutter (19456): 600
I/flutter (19456): 900
I/flutter (19456): 1000
I/flutter (19456): 1200
```

Comment: I've tried both of the above solutions but still I'm getting this error. Exception caught by widgets library
type '(dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(ProductModel, ProductModel) => int' of 'compare'                                                                                       and also this error                                                                                                                    Class 'int' has no instance method 'sort'.
Receiver: 1200
Tried calling: sort(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => dynamic)

Comment: @MaidaFarooqi: In my case, it's working fine. Maybe its another issue. Can you show which code you are using for comparison

Comment: Yes.I've tried and it's working fine but I've to print the results in Text widget of listview. Actually the sort function is causing trouble when I'm writing in the list view so I made a separate function of it and still getting error.

Comment: func() { ProductScreen.name=true;  products.sort((a, b) =>a.price.compareTo(b.price)); for (ProductModel p in products) {  Text(p.price.toString());     } }      in main class listvie
child:ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return ListTile(
           title:Text(products[index].name),
              leading:products[index].i,
              subtitle:Column(
                children:<Widget>[ !ProductScreen.name?Text("\$${products[index].price}"),:func(),//Text(func)

Comment: why you are sorting this previously rather then runtime?

Comment: because on runtime it's showing error on sort function as it has return type void.       if (!ProductScreen.name) Text("\$${products[index].price}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),)                                                                                                 else
                      products.sort((a, b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price));
          for (ProductModel p in products) {
          Text(p.price.toString());
          },

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
Comparator<ProductModel> priceComparator = (a,b) => a.price.compareTo(b.price);
products.sort(priceComparator);
```